# How to align div position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am creating the script to show the preview of uploaded image on client side with the option to remove it.

I have done all of this but the problem with the UI part the position of close icon is not top-right aligned.

Here is the code and the JSfiddle link, to test it on JSfiddle add the image by browse button.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('div').on('click', '.closeDiv', function() {
    $(this).prev().remove();
    $(this).remove();
    $('#upload-file').val("");
  });

  var fileInput = document.getElementById("upload-file");

  fileInput.addEventListener("change", function(e) {

    var filesVAR = this.files;

    showThumbnail(filesVAR);

  }, false);



  function showThumbnail(files) {
    var file = files[0]

    var $thumbnail = $('#thumbnail').get(0);

    var $image = $("<img>", {
      class: "imgThumbnail"
    });
    var $pDiv = $("<div>", {
      class: "divThumbnail",
      style: "float: left"
    });
    var $div = $("<div>", {
      class: "closeDiv",
      style: "float: right"
    }).html('X');

    $pDiv.append($image, $div).appendTo($thumbnail);
    var reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $image[0].src = e.target.result;
    }
    var ret = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    $image.on('load', function() {
      ctx.drawImage($image[0], 100, 100);
    })
  }
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.closeDiv {
  width: 20px;
  height: 21px;
  background-color: rgb(35, 179, 119);
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px rgb(74, 72, 72);
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
}
.pDiv {
  float: left;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thumbnail"></div>
<input type="file" id="upload-file" accept="image/*" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r0taz01L/11/

Comment: Just to note, questions should include all the relevant code to replicate the issue in the question itself (a JS Fiddle alone is not suitable just incase the link dies). I've edited your question to include all the necessary code.

Comment: Title and description improvments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to give

```
 .divThumbnail {
position: relative;
}
```

and closeDiv to this style

```
.closeDiv {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 21px;
    background-color: rgb(35, 179, 119);
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px rgb(74, 72, 72);
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px;
    right:0px;
}
```

here is completed solutions 
http://jsfiddle.net/r0taz01L/12/